# Is there a Hive equivalent of SQL "not like"

Tags: syntax, hive, sql-like

While Hive supports positive like queries: ex.

> select * from table_name where column_name **like 'root~%'**;

Hive **Does not** support negative like queries: ex.

> select * from table_name where column_name **not like 'root~%'**;

Does anyone know an equivalent solution that Hive does support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual if you haven't. I reference it all the time when I'm writing queries for hive.

I haven't done anything where I'm trying to match part of a word, but you might check out `RLIKE` (in this section https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#Relational_Operators)

This is probably a bit of a hack job, but you could do a sub query where you check if it matches the positive value and do a `CASE` (http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hive/LanguageManual/UDF#Conditional_Functions) to have a known value for the main query to check against to see if it matches or not.

Another option is to write a UDF which does the checking.

I'm just brainstorming while sitting at home with no access to Hive, so I may be missing something obvious. :)

Hope that helps in some fashion or another. \^_^/

EDIT: Adding in additional method from my comment below.

For your provided example colName RLIKE '[^r][^o][^o][^t]~\w' That may not be the optimal REGEX, but something to look into instead of sub-queries

Comment: it looks like CASE will do what I need it to, but Im having trouble with the syntax. Does it go in the Select clause or the Where clause? This attempt failed: 'create table tmp_table as CASE WHEN a.username like 'twitter~%' THEN '' ELSE select sum(file_size) as storage, sum(bandwidth) as bandwidth from tmp_sites_compare1 a;' But it doesnt make sense to me for it to be in the where clause... Thoughts?

Comment: @CMaury: The `CASE` is in the `SELECT` clause. `SELECT CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END AS colName FROM...`

Comment: @CMaury: I started playing around with `RLIKE` for something at my work, and while it's not going to be optimal for all situations you can use the regex 'not' `^`. For your provided example `colName RLIKE '[^r][^o][^o][^t]~\\w'` That may not be the optimal REGEX, but something to look into instead of sub-queries

Comment: Haha. yea, that is even better than sub-queries... Thanks for all the help. Accepting your answer.

Comment: To do a  negative regex lookahead you can do `(?!root)` but note that if you are doing that in bash you will need to escape the `!` like `\!` so bash doesn't think it is an event. so `hive -e "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE colName RLIKE '^(?\!root~).*$'"` should work exactly like the not like in other DBs

Answer (score 54):

Try this:

```
Where Not (Col_Name like '%whatever%')
```

also works with rlike:

```
Where Not (Col_Name rlike '.*whatever.*')
```

Answer (score 8):

NOT LIKE have been supported in HIVE version 0.8.0, check at JIRA.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1740

Answer (score 6):

In SQL:

```
select * from table_name where column_name not like '%something%';
```

In Hive:

```
select * from table_name where not (column_name like '%something%');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regexp_extract works as well:

```
select * from table_name where regexp_extract(my_column, ('myword'), 0) = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can make it like this:

```
select * from table_name where not column_name like 'root~%';
```

Answer (score 0):

In impala you can use `!=` for not like:

```
columnname != value
```

Answer (score 0):

as @Sanjiv [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26632143/8374837)

hive has support `not like`

```
0: hive> select * from dwtmp.load_test;
+--------------------+----------------------+
| load_test.item_id  | load_test.item_name  |
+--------------------+----------------------+
| 18282782           | NW                   |
| 1929SEGH2          | BSTN                 |
| 172u8562           | PLA                  |
| 121232             | JHK                  |
| 3443453            | AG                   |
| 198WS238           | AGS                  |
+--------------------+----------------------+
6 rows selected (0.224 seconds)

0: hive> select * from dwtmp.load_test where item_name like '%ST%';
+--------------------+----------------------+
| load_test.item_id  | load_test.item_name  |
+--------------------+----------------------+
| 1929SEGH2          | BSTN                 |
+--------------------+----------------------+
1 row selected (0.271 seconds)

0: hive> select * from dwtmp.load_test where item_name not like '%ST%';
+--------------------+----------------------+
| load_test.item_id  | load_test.item_name  |
+--------------------+----------------------+
| 18282782           | NW                   |
| 172u8562           | PLA                  |
| 121232             | JHK                  |
| 3443453            | AG                   |
| 198WS238           | AGS                  |
+--------------------+----------------------+
5 rows selected (0.247 seconds)
```